# What does this number indicate in SO URL

Tags: support, hyperlinks

If you see this SO question URL

***http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/23887252/blocking-an-input-box-with-respect-to-dropdownlist-value***

What does this number indicate 23887252== Question Number?

Comment: It's the unique ID. It means the question title can change but the links still work. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887252/what-is-that-id-number-all-about

Answer (score 5):

It is the post Id in the database.

This is used to retrieve the post and related entities and display them.

Comment: Entities... it's all about entities.