# Subsite question ID jumps by 1000. Why?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I've noticed each Stack Exchange question has had a number in the URL for a while. This number grows for each new question asked, usually by 3 or 4. So I assumed that each answer added to a site increased the number that would be showed in the URL by 1.

[What does this number indicate in SO URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232244/what-does-this-number-indicate-in-so-url) gives some data about this and mentioned entities. I'd assume these are comments, questions and answers.

But looking through the [cseducators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest) subsite's question list, I noticed a steep drop-off from [2511/Letters of Recommendation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/best-practices-for-letters-of-recommendation-in-cs) to [1509/Plagiarism before the Final Submission](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1509/what-should-a-teacher-do-with-information-about-plagiarism-before-the-final-subm).

What could cause such a big gap? While it's reasonable that there might be a flurry of comments to make, say, a change in question ID by 50, 1000 seems very high.